# How to automatically update webpage version within requests.put()?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, httprequest, python-requests-html

I am using the requests.put() method within my script to automatically update a webpage. The problem being that the automation script is not completely automated as it should be. Let me show you the snippet of the code which is causing the issue:

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    
    # Just a string payload being extracted from previous lines of code not shown here
    pass_string = str(soup).replace('\"', '\\"')

    data = '{"id":"525424594","type":"page", "title":"Update status","space":{"key":"CSSAI"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"' + pass_string + '","representation":"storage"}}, "version":{"number":44}}'


    response = requests.put('https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594', headers=headers, data=data,
                            auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Automation@ai.com', 'AIengineering1@ai'))
```

So, in the JSON string called **data** we have the the key called "version":{"number":44} which is used to update the webpage such that we do not have any conflicts regarding page versions. And it should be updated every time the contents of the webpage changes.
There are two cases which will change the "version" of the webpage:

1. Once I send my requests.put() http request the page gets updated and version has to be incremented by 1.
2. If someone updates the webpage by going to the webpage link itself and manually changes the content of that page the version gets also updated.

For case 1 I can have a .txt file which will record the previous version of the webpage such that each time I execute the script I can read from .txt file the previous version and the version automatically increments it by 1 within script, writes that version to the .txt file, and executes the command using the incremented version.
But for case 2 I would not know if someone had changed the version in the webpage itself and so it would be hard to know the current version of that webpage to increment to.
Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "changes the version in the website itself"?

Comment: @Anonymous By that I mean in confluence webpages we have an option called edit where someone can click edit and change some content by typing or attaching something.

Comment: Couldn't you have that button make the PUT request?

Comment: @Anonymous What do you mean? How can Edit button make a PUT request? PUT request should be made within script. The Edit button is in a webpage.

Comment: The edit button could trigger the website's code to make a PUT request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pondering some more I found the required solution. If anyone has a better solution please post it here.

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    
    # Just a string payload being extracted from previous lines of code not shown here
    pass_string = str(soup).replace('\"', '\\"')

    data = '{"id":"525424594","type":"page", "title":"Update status","space":{"key":"CSSAI"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"' + pass_string + '","representation":"storage"}}, "version":{"number":2}}'


    response = requests.put('https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594', headers=headers, data=data,
                            auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Automation@ai.com', 'AIengineering1@ai'))

    if response.json()["statusCode"] == 409:
        error_message = "Version must be incremented on update. Current version is: "
        if error_message in response.json()["message"]:
            current_version = response.json()["message"].split(error_message)[1]
            version_num = int(current_version) + 1
            data = '{"id":"525424594","type":"page", "title":"Update Status","space":{"key":"CSSAI"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"' + pass_string + '","representation":"storage"}}, "version":{"number":' + str(
                version_num) + '}}'
            response = requests.put('https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594', headers=headers, data=data,
                                    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Automation@ai.com', 'AIengineering1@ai'))
    else:
        print(response.json())
        sys.exit(1)
```

Basically I am gathering the current version number from the failed response and incrementing it by one to send the new request. However, this does mean that our first request will always be a failed request.